# Python rename files to sequenced letters

Tags: python, linux, sequence, rename

So I have found this python script that will allow me to rename all the files in a directory into a sequence of numbers, whilst keeping the order of the files.

```
import os
import sys

top_dir = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
files = os.listdir( top_dir )

for index,item in enumerate(files):
    if os.path.isdir( os.path.join(top_dir,item) ):
       files.pop(index)

files.sort()

duplicates = []
last_index = None
for index,item in enumerate(files):

    last_index = index
    extension = ""
    if '.' in item:
        extension = '.' + item.split('.')[-1]
    old_file = os.path.join(top_dir,item)
    new_file = os.path.join(top_dir,str(index) + extension  )
    while os.path.isfile(new_file):
          last_index += 1
          new_file = os.path.join(top_dir,str(last_index) + extension  )
    print( old_file + ' renamed to ' + new_file ) 
    os.rename(old_file,new_file)
```

Would anyone know how I can change this script to allow the renaming process to be composed of a sequence of a-z letters using 3 letters from the order aaa to aaz to aza to azz to zza- to zzz

Comment: It's definitely doable; but what would be your complete alphabet? downcase ascii letters? and above all, what did you try?

Comment: assuming suffixes `[a-z]` ... what happens when you have more than 26 files? `filey`, `filez` ... ??? `fileya`? `fileay`? something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
letters=({a..z}{a..z}{a..z}) j=

for i in *; do
    echo mv "$i" "${letters[j++]}"
done
```

- `mv "$i" "$i$-{letters[j++]}"` (or similar) to add suffixes instead of replacing the whole name
- If the commands look ok, remove `echo` to run them (when running again, don't forget to reset `j=` (empty) in an interactive shell - not neccesary in a script)

Comment: Nice solution, works great for OP use-case +1

Comment: Im still only learning bash, would you know how to save this as a script and run it in a directory using linux. As I struggled to get it working. thanks

Comment: Copy and paste to a file like `aaa-rename.bash`. Run it by typing `bash /path/to/aaa-rename.bash` (or go to the directory with `cd`, and `bash aaa-rename.bash` from the same directory). If the output looks good, remove `echo` (using `nano` editor for example), to run for real.